# Sort a checkboxlist alphabetically, in place, in C# after the data is added

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, checkboxlist

The controls (`ListItems`) are created dynamically, so there is no possibility to sort pre-insertion.

I've attempted a solution, which does the job (sort on a list then reconstructing the control) but I would like a more elegant solution.

For the sake of completeness below is my current solution:

```
        List<ListItem> lli = new List<ListItem>();

        foreach (ListItem item in cblGIFFlags.Items) lli.Add(item);
        cblGIFFlags.Items.Clear();
        bool sorting = true;
        while (sorting)
        {
            sorting = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < lli.ToArray().Length - 1; i++)
            {
                ListItem x = lli[i];
                ListItem y = lli[i + 1];
                if (Comparer<String>.Default.Compare(x.Text,y.Text) > 0)
                {
                    lli[i] = y;
                    lli[i + 1] = x;
                    sorting = true;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (ListItem item in lli) cblGIFFlags.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: `implementation of bubble sort` which I'm sure everyone is familiar with?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko pretty sure Op said what was tried-- sorted manually and re-constructed the control.

Comment: @dbaseman exactly. Adding the implementation would be totally pointless and just clutter up everything with completely irrevalant code which doesn't help to solve the issue (well I suppose it solves the issue in ONE way...)

Comment: @dbaseman, thats why I said show not tell.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Consider what I have implemented irrevalant for the scope of the question, thanks!

Comment: @hkf, if you hadn't implemented anything I would be saying the same thing. What you have written so far could be the best solution but we cant tell as you haven't posted it. Unless its a lot of lines of code its not going to clutter up the question so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since [ListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx#Y0) implements IEnumerable, I thought maybe I could cast to IEnumerable<ListItem> or something.  I couldn't figure out how to do that cast.  Here's the best I could come up with:

```
var items = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (ListItem item in listBox.Items) items.Add(item);
listBox.Items.Clear();
listBox.Items.AddRange(items.OrderBy(i=>i.Value).ToArray());
```

Comment: While this is a more elegant solution it does not sort in place.. you're still having to add/clear/add the items.

Comment: @hkf Yeah, I don't know what kind of collection that is (**ListItemCollection**) but it doesn't support the normal Linq operations.  Note that for the above to work you need to add a reference to System.Linq.dll.